# Story About Choosing The Future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Long ago and far away, I read a story about two scientists with a get-rich-quick scheme.

They created two tunnels with amusement park special effects. Folks would come to them, get shown a future that's a utopia for Tunnel #1 and a ruined wasteland for Tunnel #2. The scientists tell them, "Whichever tunnel you go through, that'll be the future you get."

While counting their fortune, they have an epiphany upon finding their clients overwhelmingly chose the barren, hopeless wasteland rather than utopia. Those people, expecting nuclear war, famine, plague, etc. will now ensure that future comes to fruition.

Comment: I remember something like this but I have no idea what it is. Maybe it's just reminiding me of a scene in "A Christmas Carol" where they go through grey swirling portals.

Comment: How long ago, roughly?

Comment: I read it in the aughts, but the story was from the 1950's-60's.

Comment: This sounds very like early Robert Sheckley in style and theme. Can I suggest a search of his work?